# How to group table's data by categorical variable values in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, grouping

I have a table and I wish to group the data from the table based on the values of a categorical variable. For example, let's say I have the following columns in a table called "data":

- **"Gender"**, which has the values 0 and 1.
- **"Age"**, a continuous variable with a wide range of numbers.

I would like to create two tables with the ages of the people based on their **Gender**. So one table for the ages of people with *Gender == 0* and another for the ages of people with *Gender == 1*. I want all the rows from the table which meet the conditions, not a summary of the data.

I have tried doing the following but it will only return empty tables:

```
data_m = groupfilter(data,"Gender",@(x) (x) == 0)
data_f = groupfilter(data,"Gender",@(x) (x) == 1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: numel will return the number of elements, are you sure you don't just want `@(x) x == 0` and `@(x) x == 1` ?

Comment: I have tried that, but it's still giving me an empty 0x2 table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the groupfilter function but you can not use something as:

```
name = ["Maria" "Jose" "Arnaldo" "Eva" "Schawarza" "Rose"]';´
gender = [0 1 1 0 0 0]';
T = table(name,gender)

male = T(T.gender==1,:)
female = T(T.gender==0,:)
```